# AWS SCP Condition disallow iam user creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, policy

I am trying to create an SCP policy to disallow creation of iam user in member accounts other than Admin (assumed role with SSO), however its not letting even the admin create the user, below is the policy I am using,

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateUser",
        "iam:CreateAccessKey",
        "iam:DeleteAccessKey",
        "iam:DeleteUser"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:sts::*:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess*/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure what's wrong in it, please help

Comment: Does the admin role have `*` permissions or at least the relevant IAM permissions? What if you remove the entire `Deny` statement, does it work then? Does the SCP explicitly grant the `iam:CreateUser` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PrincipalArn should be:

```
arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess*
```

To get an valid ARN for SSO assumed roles, you need to change `arn:aws:sts::*:assumed-role` by `arn:aws:iam::*:role`.

Additionally, this represents the SSO group, so you do not need to add `/*` after the group name. So the following ARN is incorrect and will not work:

```
arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess*
```

---

Reference:

[Implement service control policy (SCP) for accounts in AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/implement-read-only-service-control-policy-in-aws-organizations/)

Comment: This worked, thanks, I was doing mistake of using user arn rather than role arn."Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/AWSReservedSSO_AWSAdministratorAccess_*"
          ]
        }
      }